# How to define a constraint in Ortools to set a limit of distinct values

Tags: c#, linear-programming, constraint-programming, or-tools

I am trying to define a constraint that is going to limit the number of unique values generated by the solver. It can generate as many duplicates as possible to solve the problem but there is a limit on unique values.

Comment: If you are using cp-sat you can create a boolean for each value indicating if the value is present and constraint their sum

Comment: that will constrain the values generated not unique values. I want to allow it to have as many duplicates as it needs but limit the distinct values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each value, create a boolean variable `selected_value` that is true iff at least one value is assigned to it.

For this you will need 2 sets of constraints:

from left to right: `selected_value` implies the value is selected

```
model.AddBoolOr([var_i_equals_value, ...]).OnlyEnforcedIf(selected_value)
```

and from right to left, the value is selected implies `selected_value` is true

```
for var_i_equals_value in ...:
    model.AddImplication(var_i_equals_value, selected_value)
```

And then you just need to constraint the sum of the selected values

```
model.Add(sum(selected_value_array) <= 10)
```

Now you need to ask if you really need integer variables, or just a matrix of Boolean variables. I suggest the latter.